# What is Application Server for ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, windows, application-server

I've worked on the .Net platform for last two years and now I'm moving on to .NET Web development.

I am confused about the Application server.
What is it ?
What are Roles?
How is it different from the Web server?

In Windows is there any Application Server program like Tomcat with Apache Server?
I read Wikipedia and MSDN, there is no any clear documentation regarding Application Server. So please advise me where I can clear my doubts.
Is there any good link?

Comment: Microsoft has a knack for fancy names, web server is actually the Application Server. Website's are known as web applications[because they are still native code executed on clr]. Roles are nothing but names given to set of permissions for example - In a form `Admin, moderator, guest` are roles which have permissions like `edit, delete, flag`

Answer (score 4):

The term application server is a bit vague - going by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server)

> An application server is a software framework that provides an
>   environment in which applications can run, no matter what the
>   applications are or what they do.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server) It is dedicated to the efficient
>   execution of procedures (programs, routines, scripts) for supporting
>   the construction of applications.

It also explain the term for web applications saying

> Later, the term took on the meaning of Web applications, but has since
>   evolved further into that of a comprehensive service layer. An
>   application server acts as a set of components accessible to the
>   software developer through an API defined by the platform itself. For
>   Web applications, these components are usually performed in the same
>   machine where the Web server is running, and their main job is to
>   support the construction of dynamic pages. However, present-day
>   application servers target much more than just Web page generation:
>   they implement services like clustering, fail-over, and
>   load-balancing, so developers can focus on implementing the business
>   logic.[3]

Going by these definitions and comparing with app servers from java world, .NET Framework along with infrastructure support from window server (e.g. IIS/Web Server) will be an application server.

Comment: Ok, IIS is the "Application Server" for dotNet apps, but for dotNet Core?

Comment: @carloreggiani, ASP.NET core can still be hosted in IIS. From Microsoft perspective windows/IIS platform remains. With dotNet core, you may host .NET app on different web servers/platforms - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows

Answer (score 4):

There are some standalone Application Servers for Windows Web based applications. Such as [NeoKernal](http://www.neokernel.com/content.agent?page_name=Home).

However, by default IIS (any version) doubles up as an Application Server **and** a Web Server.

This is only relevant when you get involved in complex / advanced deployments. The application server inside IIS comes into play when you set permissions and thread pools for a particular website (dedicated / non dedicated) etc.

Just relax, install Visual Studio and start building :)

Answer (score 2):

[Internet Information Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) (IIS) is the application server on Windows, being similar to Tomcat

Answer (score 1):

I think AppFabric is like application server ([AppFabric info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849)). Hope this link helps you.